# Configure widget from command of other widget in tkinter

Tags: python, configuration, tkinter

I have a checkbox and two scales. If the checkbox is unticked, I want to set a scale to 0 and disable them using configure.

**What I can't figure out is how to alter the scales from a command from the checkbox.**

```
alp         = Checkbutton( self, variable   = self.ifalphagrams,
                                 onvalue    = 'yes',
                                 offvalue   = 'no',
                                 command    = disscale
                                 )
soundspeed2 = Scale(       self, from_      =  0,
                                 to         = 10,
                                 resolution =  1,
                                 orient     = HORIZONTAL,
                                 variable   = self.alphaletter
                                 )
```

above are the two elements, if that helps.

Comment: By the way, if `disscale` method is part of the class you created, you need to use `self.disscale`.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. All you've showed us is the widgets. What does disscale do?

Comment: Disscale did nothing at the time because I couldn't access soundspeed2 from it when it was called from alp. By making soundspeed2 global I managed to make it work, but I'm not sure that's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a if else in your 'disscale' function:

```
def disscale(self, event):
  a = int(alp.get())
  if a==1:
    ##display soundspeed2 
  else:
    ##Dont display soundspeed2
```

Hope it helps!